# Como chamar uma Function javaScript em c#

Tags: c#

```
var inputElements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (HtmlElement i in inputElements){

            if(i.GetAttribute("name").Equals("user")){
                i.InnerText = "Teste";
            }

            if(i.GetAttribute("name").Equals("password")){

                i.Focus();
                i.InnerText = "1234";                   
            }               
        }

        var buttonElements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("class");
        foreach (HtmlElement b in inputElements){

     if(b.GetAttribute("href").Equals("javascript:submitForm()")){      

                SendKeys.SendWait("click");
            }
        }
```

//Ex HTML da pagina:

1. `<a  title="Clique aqui para fazer o login" href="javascript:submitFunction()" </a>`

Se alguem poder me ajudar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode chamar o `submitForm()` com o método `InvokeScript`

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("submitForm");
```

Comment: Deu certo Obrigado.